# E: Unable to locate package mysql E: Unable to locate package server

Tags: linux, ubuntu

what to do with this i am in **linux** terminal.I am trying to install **mysql** in my system

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the package 'mysql' is not found in systems repositorys list (and to my knowlege, does not exist).

However, the 'mysql-server' package does exist (assumining you want the server) and it can be instaled by ([Install MySQL using APT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/)):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

There are also different ways that MySQL can be installed outlined on the MySQL Website: [MySQL Installtion Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation.html)